# Estimate variance of sub-sets from overall variance

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, online-algorithms, sum

I am looking for a way to estimate the variance of a summed sub-set based on the variance of those sums.

```
Si = sum( Ai )
S = { S0...Sn }
V = variance( S )
```

That is, each sample value `Si` is actually the sum of a set `Ai`. `V` is then the normal variance of the set `S`.

Is there any way to estimate the variance of the values in sets `Ai` using the final variance, or some result from the above?

*Currently I do `variance / (len(Ai)^2)` but the value is then an averaged value of the variance. I'm wondering if there is a way to improve upon this.*

---

*Background:* The reason the I don't calculate variance on individual samples from the population is that the measurement is then too small. I am measuring elapsed time, and so individual samples the elapses time is too small for the timing device to measure, so instead I do a series of operations and calculation the time for the whole group.

*Note:* In the application I have no ability to store samples and am using an online algorithm (Knuth).

Comment: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10441/how-to-calculate-the-variance-of-a-partition-of-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the strong assumptions that all the various $A_{i,j}$ are identically and independently distributed, and if there are the same number in each sum $S_j$, then since $$Var(S_j) = Var\left(\sum_i A_{i,j}\right) = \sum_i Var(A_{i,j})$$ your method is reasonable.

But this does depend on what is really happening: if the $A_{i,j}$s are correlated, or if their population means or variances vary with $j$, or if there are different numbers in each sum, then you will need another approach.